# Get key/id from array of objects

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript I've got the following code to find a specific object in an array:

```
records.find(function (obj) { return obj.time === tmp_date; })
```

Is it possible to get the key/id of the object from the array `records`?

Comment: Post your object here

Comment: You could probably use [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) instead of `find`, so that you know the index in the `records` array of the match you got.

Comment: every object has a keys() method for this. You can use Object.keys(nameOfYourObject). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Comment: `.find()` returns the found object. So it should be as simple as: `const record = records.find( ... ); const id = record.id;` Or do you mean the index? Then use `.findIndex()`

Comment: `.findIndex()` simply returns `Array.prototype.findIndex callback must be a function`, if I do `records.findIndex(function (obj) { return obj.time === tmp_date; })`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming `records` looks like this (since you didn't provide it) :

```
let records = [
  {
     id : 1,
     time : 10
  },
  {
     id : 2,
     time : 20
  }
]
```

then you can simply get the index of the matched object this way :

```js
 let records = [
      {
         id : 1,
         time : 10
      },
      {
         id : 2,
         time : 20
      }
    ],
    tmp_date = 20,
    index;
    
for(let i in records){
  if(records[i].time===tmp_date){
    index = i;
    break;
  }
}

console.log(`Found time ${tmp_date} at index ${index}.`)
```

Comment: The objects do not have `id`, it's the `index` I'm looking for. I simply want to know of the found object is the last in the array.

Answer (score -1):

`find()` method on array will return the first matching object based on the condition. You can then fetch the `id` of that object like we access other properties.

```js
var records = [{time:10, id:1}, {time:20, id:2}, {time:30, id:3}];

var id = records.find(function (obj) { return obj.time === 20; }).id;

console.log(id);
```

Comment: find() is not supported by IE, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find . Use a polyfill

Comment: Yes I am aware about IE support. `find()` was already there in the question. I have explained how it works and one can fetch the required property from there.